# SQLite3 Update statement

Tags: python, sqlite, sql-update

I have a database setup with python and sqlite3. 
I need to update my stock database so that I can change information about the item.

The current code I have is:

```
itemname = e0.get()
quantity = e1.get()
manufacturer = e2.get()
itemnumber = e3.get()
price = e4.get()
curriculumlink = e5.get()
yeargrouplink = e6.get()
location = e7.get()
```

All of these are taken from tkinter entry boxes, they currently hold information I have loaded into them based on what information the database already has about the item.

```
cursor = db.cursor()
sql = "UPDATE items SET quantity = '%s' WHERE name = '%s';" % quantity.strip(), itemname.strip()
cursor.execute(sql)
db.commit()
```

This code encounters an error and doesn't update the quantity. If anyone has any suggestions for this I would really appreciate it.

However, is there any way of update all of the properties above in one sql statement. All of the fields in the database are the same as the names of the user input above.

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: "This code encounters an error and doesn't update the quantity" - Could you please share the error?

Comment: What are the values of `itemname` and `quantity`?

Comment: This is the error: TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

Comment: first you should use the sqlite engine executes string formatting
`cur.execute("UPDATE items SET quantity=?WHERE name=?",[qty,name])` second you should really consider using an ORM like sqlalchemy

Comment: itemname and quantity are values got from the users input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sql = "UPDATE items SET quantity = '%s' WHERE name = '%s';" % (quantity.strip(), itemname.strip())
```

will fix your problem(it was not interpretting the tuple without the parenthesis)  *but* you should really us sqlite3 engine execute formatting

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE items SET quantity=?WHERE name=?",[qty,name])
```

and really you should probably be using an ORM like sqlalchemy which allows you to switch database engines easily and represents all the data as classes

```
 class Item(Base):
     __tablename__ = "items"
     name = Column(String,primary_key=True)
     qty = Column(Integer,default=0)
```